# how to execute a terminal command in c#

Tags: c#, bash, process

I read many post, from them there is this one

c# - Opening the terminal process and pass commands?

I do the exact same thing in my code

```
Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + command + " \"";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.Start ();
```

where command = export DISPLAY=:0.0

and it goes to my catch, "pplicationName='/bin/bash', CommandLine='-c " cd .. "', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= The system cannot find the file specified."

what do I do differently? even if I try to juste set command = "cd .." it doesn't work

Comment: "goes to your catch", can you tell us what the error is that you get in the catch? Specifically the type of error and the message that it contains.

Comment: sorry though I said it. it's now in the question

Comment: Where you are setting StartInfo.FileName - I notice that's a relative path not a full path. Have you tried specifying the full path to the exe just in case it's not resolving the correct path which is causing the problem?

Comment: Are you running this on Windows, or on Linux via Mono?

Comment: @Darrell that *is* a full path on Linux systems.

Comment: @crashmstr - ah no idea from your question which O/S this was but guessed windows incorrectly :)

Comment: ah that may be the answer... I'm debugging on window but it will run on linux thought.... I'll try it in linux to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably try setting the full path the executable.

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/SOMEPATH/Bash.exe";
```

I'm assuming as you are specifying a relative path, it's not resolving it. Possibly because you aren't setting a working directory for the process so it's current dir and the current dir you think it has, are different.

Comment: thanks a lot it's as you said!! however for debuggin purpose it's on windows... what is the path to bin bash on windows 7?? how can I find it?

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim there is no bash shell on Windows unless you install one. Also, there is no benefit from doing a `cd` command in a shell (it won't affect the running application's current working folder).